# PHP - Use value from array outside of the array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array which contains multiple other arrays. These arrays have a value called [note] which references a variable called `$theNote` which is located above/outside the array. This variable holds a simple template with a few spans.

```
$theNote = '<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is $thename</span>';
```

I have an array called `client_infos` which contains multiple arrays inside like

```
  'client_infos' => array (
       array (
            'name' => 'John smith',
            'note' => $theNote,
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Mary smith',
            'note' => $theNote,
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
    );
```

There will be an unknown number of names eventually. What I need to be able to do is in my template, call `$theNote` in a loop or something and the following to be outputted...

```
<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is John Smith</span>
```

As you can see, the [note] info in the array uses the `$theNote` varible, this outputs a block of code with a variable inside called `$thename`. I do not know how to get my [name] info.. into the `$thename` variable.

Basically some how get. `$thename` inside `$theNote to = the current array [name] value`.

The reason for all of this is so that I can easily update "the note" code once, without having to do it in all the child arrays.

I hope I am being clear enough, any ideas?

Comment: Also, any help with actually naming this question better?

Comment: So you want to loop over client_infos to output each ['name']? Is that it?

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to use a class here:

```
class Client
{
    private $name;
    private $prepend;
    private $append;
    private $formatting;

    // place a constructor here

    // create getter and setter for the properties
    public function getNote() {
        return '<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is ' . $this->name . '</span>'
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good considering of Object oriented programming in such scenarios, wherein you can describe a client in far better way with a class object rather an array.

Comment: It's not always better to use classes, especially, when a procedure like this can be done with simple `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right, you can replace the `$theName` with a unique variable like `%THE_NAME%` and do something like this:

```
$theNote = '<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is %THE_NAME%</span>';

$client_infos = array (
       array (
            'name' => 'John smith',
            'note' => $theNote,
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Mary smith',
            'note' => $theNote,
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
    );

foreach( $client_infos as $arr )
{
    echo str_replace( '%THE_NAME%', $arr['name'], $arr['note'] ) , '<br/>';
}
```

## Output

```
Hello my name is John smith
Hello my name is Mary smith
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
     $theNote = '<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is {name}</span>';
```

then to echo:

```
    echo str_replace('{name}', $client_infos[0]['name'], $client_infos[0]['note']);
```

Or to replace {name} in all the array

```
   for($i=0; $i<count($client_infos); $i++){
      $client_infos[$i]['note']=str_replace('{name}', $client_infos[$i]['name'], $client_infos[$i]['note']);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring part of `$theNote` within the array itself:

```
$theNote = '<span class="icon"></span><span>Hello my name is ';
$theNote2 = '</span>';
 'client_infos' => array (
       array (
            'name' => 'John smith',
            'note' => $theNote . $thename . $theNote2, 
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Mary smith',
            'note' => $theNote . $thename . $theNote2,
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'formatting' => 'html',
        ),
    );
```

Good luck!